# Firefox right-click-menu black

Tags: firefox

I just upgraded firefox to v. 46.0 and found out that something funny is going on there.

When performing a right-click the opening window has got a black background and the writing is in white. That used to be the other way round.
The same is true when typing something in the adress-field.

However this phenomenon is restricted to the usage of firefox in Linux / Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
(I am running Ubuntu as a virtual machine utilizing VMware Workstation 12 Player).
When running Firefox within my physical machine (WIN 8.1, 64bit) everything is as it used to be
(black writing on white background).

Is there anyone out there who has noticed this as well and can tell me more about it?
One has to say that the look of it is quite strange and takes some getting used to.

Comment: Sounds like Firefox is following the gtk3 theme settings. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/04/firefox-46-now-available-download

Comment: Hi xangua, thanks for your reply and for providing the link. You´re perfectly right. The change of the colour of the background is exactly as depicted on the respective page. At least I have an explanation for this behaviour. Greetings. Rosika

Comment: Even worse: for me the same combo (Firefox 46.0 on Kubuntu 14.04.4 LTS) renders tooltips as black on black. Have you seen this, too?

Comment: No, I haven´t. But I´m using Ubuntu at the moment instead of Kubuntu. So I can´t really say anything about that. Perhaps Kubuntu 16.04 will get rid of the problem? Perhaps this page will give you a bit more information: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/Beta2/Kubuntu

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is expected. In the “new” section of the [release notes of Firefox 46](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/46.0/releasenotes/), there is the following bullet:

> GTK3 integration (GNU/Linux only)

That means that Firefox tries to look like most other (GTK3) applications starting with version 46. For example, open the text editor gedit and right click in the open window there: it also shows a black context menu with white text. It’s probably just something to get used to.

Your browser under Windows looks different because Firefox tries to look like other Windows applications there.

Comment: Hi Chriki, thanks for the info. O.K., it seems that not much can be done about it and we have to accept the changes. Also interesting to learn that Firefox wants to adapt itself with respect to Windows/Ubuntu environment.